# Downloading A File To AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, storage

I'm using **youtube-dl** to download video on **s3 bucket**.
I have already mounted the s3 bucket named **apnamusic** to the folder name
**apnamusic** (which is same).

But when the file is downloaded it is consuming the storage of vm-machine and s3 storage both.
All the files are showing in s3 bucket and every thing is fine.

when I run this command:

```
df -h
```

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            488M     0  488M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M   11M   89M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1      9.7G  6.6G  3.2G  68% /
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
s3fs            256T     0  256T   0% /apnamusic
```

Here we can clearly see that **/dev/svda1** has used **6.6G** of storage.

**Here I want that the Downloaded file should directly go into s3 without consuming vm-instance storage.**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you add your question, please?

Comment: `/dev/xvda1` also contains your operating system.

Comment: s3fs-fuse has a local file cache.  Your s3fs version and the mount options you are using may be useful... also, this question probably belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) rather than Stack Overflow -- but please review those sites' help pages and see which site seems like the correct one. 
Please don't cross-post.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
s3fs apnamusic -o use_cache=/tmp -o allow_other -o uid=33 -o mp_umask=002 -o multireq_max=5 /apnamusic
```

I was using the above command. In which **-o** flag i.e. **use_cache=/tmp** was set, this was caching the files in **/tmp/apnamusic** directory.